# Closing ajax popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, popup, popupwindow

I have an ajax popup box (pasted below) that works, but I don't know how to close it. I tried adding .dialog('close') to the success line like this - $('#dialog-ajax').html(data).dialog('close');

That didn't work. I also tried replacing that line with the following:

```
if (data.success) {
    App.success(data.success);
    $('#dialog-ajax').dialog('close');
}
```

Again, no go. Thanks for your help.

Here is the html code:

```
<?php if ($this->details['changeLink'] && !$this->header_part) { ?>
    <label class="shipping">{{Tracking number}}:</label>
    <input id="tracking" class="fleft small" type="text" value="<?php echo $this->details['purchase']->tracking ?>" />
    <button id="change" class="small-button red-button fleft">{{Change}}   </button>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.isFunction($.fn.selectbox)) {
        $('select').selectbox();
    }
    <?php if ($this->details['changeLink']) { ?>

            $('#change').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $this->details['changeLink'] ?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        id: <?php echo $this->details['purchase']->id ?>,
                        status: $('#shipping-status').val(),
                        tracking: $('#tracking').val(),
                        company: $('#company').val()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        loading.loadFancy($('#dialog-ajax'));
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#dialog-ajax').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        <?php if ($this->successfu_edite) { ?>
                        App.success('{{Purchase is successfully changed!}}');
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

});
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery dialog ('#dialog-ajax').dialog('close') should work. Please check the browser console for errors and share the entire html and js code snippet.

Comment: @HectorBarbossa Here is the html and js snippet.  Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: @ian did you tried what i suggest just below !!

Comment: @PacMan  Yes, I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @ian make sure if the data.success is true by a simple alert , also try the same code by replacing $(this).css("display","none"); with $(this).hide();

Comment: @PacMan  The replacement code didn't work.  Couldn't get the alert but I know it is working because the db values are changing.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @ian see my edit answer and try again

Comment: @PacMan that didn't work either.

Comment: @ian that's kind of illogic !! here is my last chance with it see the edited answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115907/discussion-between-ian-and-pacman).

Comment: what does loadFancy function do?

Answer (score 0):

well i'm not sure if it may work or not but logically it should 
try this

```
if (data.success) {
/*when the user click outside the pop up*/
$("#dialog-ajax").dialog('destroy').remove();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call has semantic errors. Add the dataType attribute and change method attribute and your $.ajax call to the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.isFunction($.fn.selectbox)) {
        $('select').selectbox();
    }
    <?php if ($this->details['changeLink']) { ?>

            $('#change').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $this->details['changeLink'] ?>',
                    //change method and dataType to reflect the following
                    method: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: <?php echo $this->details['purchase']->id ?>,
                        status: $('#shipping-status').val(),
                        tracking: $('#tracking').val(),
                        company: $('#company').val()
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        loading.loadFancy($('#dialog-ajax'));
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            $("#dialog-ajax").fadeOut(900,'swing',function(){
                                $(this).css("display","none");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });

        <?php if ($this->successfu_edite) { ?>
                        App.success('{{Purchase is successfully changed!}}');
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

});
</script>
```